# Using cmd in a java program

Tags: java, solr

I am trying to send differents commands into a java program to start my solr server 
My problem is that I a trying to send first the command

```
cd ~/Desktop/PPE/solr-4.10.3/example
```

and then

```
java -jar start.jar
```

Using the line

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Bug I get an error no such file available. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: you need to pass the absolute path of `start.jar` !!

Comment: There's not really a lot of detail here. Could you edit your question to show the actual code that you're using to construct and run the command string? And add the specific errors or exception traces that you get when running the command?

Answer (score 0):

```
java -jar /path/to/file/start.jar
```

you have not given the path of the jar file. This is why it is giving this error, and I hope you have java in your environment variables.

Comment: Hello, 
I have already tried it but it is not working

I get :
java.io.FileNotFoundException: No XML configuration files specified in start.config or command line.
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:502)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:96)

Usage: java -jar start.jar [options] [properties] [configs]
       java -jar start.jar --help  # for more information

Comment: you are running this all via a java program right??

Comment: open cmd and run this command --> java -jar start.jar and let me know can you execute it?